# NullReferenceException When binding List<View> between Control and ViewModel in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.forms, binding, controls, nullreferenceexception

I have a problem with binding List of View elements between control and viewModel.

I created a ContentView and included it in a ContentPage. I need to create Grid.Children within ContentView dynamically by adding to the Grid a List of BoxView elements created within the ViewModel.

I managed to bind different control(e.g. Label) successfully, however when I attempt to bind the List of Views, I get an error.

First error appears when navigating to the ContentPage containing ContentView, the page doesn't event load and I get:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Your app has entered a break state, but there is no code to show because all threads were executing external code (typically system or framework code).

So, at this point I removed binding from from the Control(markup inside ContentPage's XAML) and page loads, but when I launch method that is supposed to populate Control's Grid with List containing BoxView elements I will not be able to pass the List to the Control, as the binding is not present at this point.

My question is, is there a way to bind List of Views between ViewModel and ContentView in Xamarin.Forms? Or am I trying to do something that will never work?

How would I refresh the Grid of ContentView as the Grid is being rendered based on List of Views created after ContentPage is loaded?

If the above is not posssible, is creating Grid's children upon ContentPage's load only option? Would it be possible then to pass List of Views as an argument to ContentPage?

My general problem here is that I need to generate Grid's children based on data I will input later based on various factors.

I hope it is possible to render/refresh Grid and it's Children after the Content Page is actually loaded.

Here is the code I have for now:

> ContentView Code Behind

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class GridView : ContentView
{
    public GridView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        
    }
    public static readonly BindableProperty ViewProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ViewList), typeof(List<View>), typeof(GridView));

    public List<View> ViewList
    {
        get
        {
            return (List<View>)GetValue(ViewProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ViewProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

> ContentView XAML

```
<AbsoluteLayout>
    <Grid x:Name="RenderedGrid" 
                  x:FieldModifier="public" 
                  ColumnSpacing="1" 
                  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1" 
                  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">    
    </Grid>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

> ContentPage code behind

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class GridPage : ContentPage
{
    public GridPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        BindingContext = new GridPageViewModel(Navigation);

    }
}
```

> ContentPage Markup

```
<ScrollView Grid.Row="1">
        <local:GridView ViewList="{Binding Path=BindingContext.ViewsList, Source={x:Reference GridPage}}"/>
</ScrollView>
```

> ContentPage's ViewModel

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public class GridPageViewModel : BaseGridViewModel
{
    
    public Classes _Classes;
    public GridView _gridView = new GridView();
    public ICommand RenderGridCommand { get; private set; }
    
    public GridPageViewModel(INavigation navigation)
    {
        
        _navigation = navigation;
        
        RenderGridCommand = new Command(() => StartRender());//used when button is hit, not when page loads.
    }
    public void StartRender()
    {
        CreateGrid();
    }
    
    public void CreateGrid()
    {
        //List<View> views = new List<View>();

        for (int i = 0; i < SomeProvidedCustomDataList.Count(); i++)
        {
            BoxView boxView = new BoxView
            {
                Color = Color.Accent,
                HeightRequest = SomeProvidedCustomDataList[i].Height,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.End,
                StyleId = SomeProvidedCustomDataList[i].Name
            };
            boxView.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGesture);
            ViewsList.Add(boxView);
        }
        //Add list of boxViews to Grid
        _gridView.RenderedGrid.Children.AddHorizontal(_gridView.ViewList);

    }
    List<View> _viewsList = new List<View>();
    public List<View> ViewsList
    {
        get => _viewsList;
        set
        {
            _viewsList = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ViewsList");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to successfully bind List<View> between ViewModel and View's ContentView Control - Xamarin.Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53215248/unable-to-successfully-bind-listview-between-viewmodel-and-views-contentview)